# is "b &= f();" thread-safe if "f()" is thread safe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Given a boolean b and a thread safe function f() that returns a boolean, is next statement thread-safe:

```
b &= f();
```

The idea is several threads execute in parallel this statement. If one of them have f returning false, b should be false. Otherwise b is true.

I guess is not atomic and it could happen that one thread reads b, freeze, meanwhile second thread read b, runs f(), apply &, then first thread wake up, runs f() and apply & using old b.

Is guaranteed that a given thread, first run f() and then reads b and then apply &?

Comment: If multiple threads are modifying `b`, you need to synchronize the access.

Comment: `&` is not special. a = something(a) is always racy. Here, something(a) => a & f().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; there's no guarantee that you'll get the right result:

1. First thread reads `b` (which is `true`)
2. Second thread reads `b` (which is `true`)
3. First thread executes `b & f()` (and found it `true`)
4. Second thread executes `b & f()` (and found it `false`)
5. Second thread writes `b` back (`b` is `false`)
6. First thread writes `b` back (and, finally, `b` is `true`)

so you have to *synchronize* the access

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: no.
The reason for that is, that the value of b needs to be obtained. If thread A saves the value and gets interrupted by thread b, which gets b and executes f, then the execution of your first thread will work on a wrong value.